# Windows Server as a PPTP Gateway

Tags: routing, windows-server-2012, nat, pptp

I have a Windows Server 2012 server at work, which is currently used as a domain controller, and an internet gateway. The current internet connection uses a USB dongle, which appears like a standard network interface in Windows. Thus, I was able to configure it using the default Routing and Remote Access administration panel by enabling NAT.

Now we have to switch ISPs, and the new ISP provides a standard Ethernet cable, *but* it requires establishing a PPTP no-encryption connection to their server in order to access the internet.

So, I installed a second ethernet NIC and now I can access the ISPs PPTP server.

However, when I create the PPTP connection in Windows, I can't see it as a network interface in the Routing and Remote Access administration panel.
I tried adding the connection to the said panel as a remote dial-in connection, but even though it could connect, no internet connection was present on the network or on the server.
I thought of sharing the PPTP connection to a loopback adapter via ICS and then NATing to the loopback adapter, but ICS and NAT can't work together. 
It would be great if there's a VPN client that creates its own interface like OpenVPN does.

So, how can I share the PPTP connection onto the network using the Windows Server's NAT? I'm totally out of ideas.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you pass traffic across the PPTP link?  What happens if you update your routes to use the PPTP link as your default gateway?

Comment: @jlehtinen Yes I can. I will try the routes thing

Answer (score 0):

We've had to install a hardware gateway anyway, so the problem is now gone with using a second NIC to connect to the hardware gateway and standard NAT configuration on the server